# Formatar data e hora com PHP

Tags: php

Eu tenho essa página que exibe os e-mails recebidos do usuário logado, junto com as respectivas datas. Estou tentando formatar a exibição de datas pelo PHP mas não está funcionando com eu esperava. Preciso que na primeira linha apareça a data PT-BR e na segunda linha a hora e o minuto, mas está aparecendo conforme a imagem. Podem me ajudar ? Segue meu código:

```
<? foreach ($resultado as &$rowmensagens) {
$datamensagem = $rowmensagens['dataenvio'];
$datamensagem = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($datamensagem));
$horamensagem = date("H:i:s", strtotime($datamensagem));

$arr_msg = explode("/", $datamensagem);
$diamsg = $arr_msg[0];
$mesmsg = $arr_msg[1];
$anomsg = $arr_msg[2];

$arr_hora = explode(":", $horamensagem);
$hora_msg = $arr_hora[0];
$minuto_msg = $arr_hora[1]; ?>

<strong><?=$diamsg?>/<?=$mesmsg?>/<?=$anomsg?></strong>
<strong><?=$hora_msg?>:<?=$minuto_msg?></strong>
```

[image]

OBS: Essa formatação já funcionou em outra ocasião e eu só copiei a estrutura pra essa página. Obrigada !

Comment: Já tentou: `date("d/m/Y", strtotime($datamensagem));`  ao invés de `date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($datamensagem));` ?

Comment: @gato Sim... ele remove a hora da primeira linha mas na segunda linha continuam aparecendo todos os registros como 21:00

Comment: Não precisa colocar na pergunta a solução e marcar RESOLVIDO a resposta com o check verde já indica a solução.

Comment: Leia a respeito de [resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sugeria que usasses este [método](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) 
será muito mais simples
poderás fazer da seguinte forma

```
(new DateTime($datamensagem))->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: santa Orientação a Objetos hein bátima xD Deu certo, obrigada !

Comment: Essa referência também me ajudou demais, valeu.

Answer (score 9):

Bom, você está complicando o seu código pra falar a verdade... a função `date()` já formata a data pro que você precisa, inclusive você já está formatando ela ali, só precisa ajustar o formato mesmo:

```
$envio = strtotime($rowmensagens['dataenvio']);
$datamensagem = date("d/m/Y", $envio);
$horamensagem = date("H:i", $envio);
```

e aí é só imprimir. Note que não precisa separar a string nem nada, é só usar.

Sobre o erro que aparecia apenas o horário 21:00, ocorre porque a função `strtotime($datamensagem)` retorna `false`, que é o valor quando a função falha. Portanto provavelmente bastaria modificar o código para converter a string vinda do banco, no formato que a função entende, e guardar o valor apenas uma vez, passando este valor para a função `date` sempre que precisar.

Saiba mais na [documentação da função date](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) e da [função strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Tentei fazer como seu exemplo mas a hora na segunda linha continua aparecendo como 21:00 =(

Comment: veja a edição, se esclarece algo

Comment: A coluna tem o valor do horário sim... eu não consegui entender pq a formatação não mostrava o horário corretamente, mas já deu certo aqui. Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: que bom que conseguiu, mas só pro pessoal que chegar aqui, editei a resposta com o que descobri por aqui.