# Como alterar formato de data em PHP

Tags: php

Olá, não sou expert em PHP, e tenho uma dúvida. Tenho este trecho de código:

```
Quartos disponíveis para
<i class="awebookingf awebookingf-calendar"></i>
<?php echo isset( $_GET['start-date']) ? $_GET['start-date'] : ''; ?> à 
<i class="awebookingf awebookingf-calendar"></i>
<?php echo isset( $_GET['end-date'] ) ? $_GET['end-date'] : ''; ?>
```

Que me retorna tipo assim, exemplo:

```
" QUARTOS DISPONÍVEIS PARA  2018-07-20 À  2018-07-24
```

Como faço pra data fina no formata dia/mês/ano ?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224948/99718

Comment: Bem-vindo gedi. Coisas que você deve estar ciente. Como marcar uma resposta como aceita https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png  Porque aceitar uma resposta https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

[**Exemplo ideone**](https://ideone.com/1znl8c)

```
//verificação se foram iniciadas
if ((isset($_GET['start-date']) && isset($_GET['end-date'])){

  // As datas
  $dataInicial = $_GET['start-date'];
  $dataFinal = $_GET['end-date'];

  // Quebra as strings nos "-" e transforma cada pedaço numa matriz
  $divisorIni = explode("-", $dataInicial);
  $divisorFin = explode("-", $dataFinal);

  // Inverte os pedaços
  $reversoIni = array_reverse($divisorIni);
  $reversoFin = array_reverse($divisorFin);

  // Junta novamente a matriz em texto separado por tracinho (-)
  $dataIni = implode("-", $reversoIni);
  $dataFin = implode("-", $reversoFin);

      echo 'Quartos disponíveis para';
      echo '<i class="awebookingf awebookingf-calendar"></i>';
      echo $dataIni;
      echo ' à <i class="awebookingf awebookingf-calendar"></i>';
      echo $dataFin;

}
```

**Outra forma:**

```
$dataInicial = $_GET['start-date'];
$divisorIni = explode("-", $dataInicial);
$dataIni = $divisorIni[2]."-".$divisorIni[1]."-".$divisorIni[0];
```