# Requisições Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Fala galera, tenho um formulário e nele um campo em que o usuário poderá selecionar um profissional para o serviço desejado, e ao selecionar tal serviço eu tenho que informar os horários disponíveis, fazendo uma requisição ajax usando um script de select no meu banco de dados pegando os supostos horários que já estão preenchidos pelo o profissional e assim usar o JS para filtrar e expor ao usuário somente os horários disponíveis, porém está dando erro. Segue o código.

```
function buscarHorarios(dataConsu)
{
  $.ajax({
      url: 'select2.php', // declarando o script que vai conter os dados
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      dataType: 'json', // o tipo de arquivo de cambio que vai ser na usado na requisição
      data:{'dataConsu': dataConsu}, 

      success: function (resultado, xhr, status)
      {
        if (resultado.statusText == "OK")
        {
          var size = resultado.responseText[0].length;
          var resp = JSON.parse(resultado.responseText);

          document.getElementById("uhoraConsult").innerHTML = "<option></option>";

          if (resp.resp == false)
          {
            for (var i = 8; i < 18; i++)
            {
              document.getElementById("uhoraConsult").innerHTML += '<option value="'+ i +'">' + i + ':00</option>';
            }
          }
          else
          {
            var t;
            for (i = 8; i < 18; i++)
            {
              t =false;
              for (var j = 0; j < size; j++)
              {
                if (resposta[0][j].Horario == i)
                {
                  t = true;
                }
                if (t == false)
                {
                  document.getElementById("uhoraConsult").innerHTML += '<option value="'+ i +'">' + i + ':00</option>';
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
},
      error: function (xhr, error, status)
      {
        alert (xhr.statusText + error + status);  
      }
  });
}
```

*
Um erro que eu consegui capturar em um alert: **OKparsererrorSyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

*

```
<?php

require_once "conexao01.php";
class Horarios
{
    public $hora1;
    public $hora2;
}

    $connecting = conectaAoMySql(); // estabelecendo conexao com o banco de dados

    $vetorHorario = []; // declarando vetor como nulo

    $dataConsulta = $medico = "";

    if(isset($_POST["dataConsu"]))
        $dataConsulta = $_POST["dataConsu"];

    if(isset($_POST["medico"]))
        $medico = $_POST["medico"];

    $SQL = "
        SELECT Horario
        FROM Agenda 
        WHERE DataConsulta = '$dataConsulta'
        AND Medico = '$medico'
    ";

    if (!$resultadoSQL = $connecting->query($SQL))
        throw new Exception ("Ocorreu uma falha: ". $connecting->error);

    if ($resultadoSQL->num_rows > 0)
    {

        while ($row = $resultadoSQL->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $vetorHorario [] = $row ["Horario"];
        }

        $vsf = json_encode($vetorHorario);
        echo $vsf;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Qual o resultado de `resultado.responseText`?

Comment: Cara até onde eu sei não da para saber, ele já cai direto na função error.

Comment: Dê um `console.log()` depois da variante `resp`. E `async: true` é desnecessário, já que o ajax é assíncrono.

Comment: Certo, o console.log não está indicando nenhum problema.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre, teria alguma ideia do que possa está acontecendo. Um dos erros é que não está retornando um JSON.

Comment: @dvd, está retornando vazio

Comment: @dvd, no campo do formulário a data é inserida no padrão BR e no banco está no padrão U.S, então no select que recebe a variável no formato BR não vai encontrar nenhuma né? Um possível erro?

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de colocar no padrão U.S no form ? Ou colocar o bd no padrão BR?

Comment: vc pode alterar o formato antes de fazer a consulta.

Comment: vc quer transformar dd-MM-yyyy para yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: Exatamente, mas qualquer maneira que seja eficiente, ta valendo

Comment: Nessa pergunta ensina como: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224948/8063

Comment: É só fazer um explode e depois concatenar os índices 2-1-0

Comment: @dvd precisaria converter do padrão BR para o U.S

Comment: Então, isso vc pode fazer tanto no JS antes de enviar o Ajax quanto no PHP ao receber a data.

Comment: teria algum exemplo em JS?