# Converter datas vindo do sql para formato brasileiro no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Boa tarde pessoal, não estou conseguindo exibir e converter as datas do sql que foram CADASTRADAS, quero exibir em formato brasileiro, alguém pode me ajudar?

CÓDIGO

```
 <?php
$sql="";
require('conexaobd.php');

if (isset($_GET["pesquisa"])) {
$nome = $_GET["pesquisa"];
$sql = "SELECT numero_de_processo, paciente, data_de_entrada, convenio, tipo_de_internacao, data_saida FROM internacoes WHERE paciente LIKE '%$nome%' ORDER BY paciente ASC";
}else

$sql = "SELECT numero_de_processo, paciente, data_de_entrada, convenio, tipo_de_internacao, data_saida FROM internacoes ORDER BY paciente ASC";


$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$inc = 0;

while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    echo "
       <tr> 

                <td>".$cont['paciente']."</td>   
                <td>".$cont['data_de_entrada']."</td> 
                <td>".$cont['convenio']."</td>
                <td>".$cont['tipo_de_internacao']."</td>
                <td>".$cont['data_saida']."</td>

                 <td> 
                 <a href='vizuinternacao.php?numero_de_processo=".$cont['numero_de_processo']."&paciente=".$cont['paciente']." target='new_blank'>
                <span class='role orange'> 
               <i class='fa fa-eye'></i>
                </span>
                </a>
                </td>

                <td> 
                 <a href='edit_internacao.php?numero_de_processo=".$cont['numero_de_processo']."&paciente=".$cont['paciente']." target='new_blank'>
                <span class='role user'> 
               <i class='fa fa-edit'></i>
                </span>
                </a>
                </td>
          </tr> 
    ";
}
?>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatar data e hora com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224948/formatar-data-e-hora-com-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu uso uma função pra isso:

```
converte_data($evento->dt_evento)
```

e a função:

```
function Converte_Data($data){
$data_nova = implode(preg_match("~\/~", $data) == 0 ? "/" : "-", array_reverse(explode(preg_match("~\/~", $data) == 0 ? "-" : "/", $data)));
return $data_nova;}
```

A parte da "function", deixa dentro do bloco php no inicio da página, já a chamada altere seu código dessa maneira:

```
<td>".converte_data($cont['data_de_entrada'])."</td>
```

Com isso a função será chamada passando a data como vem do banco e retornando a data formatada para o nosso padrão.

Testa ai...

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... Sou novo em programação, a pagina está retornando erro, não sei oq substituir nesse seu código e aonde colocar... Se conseguir me ajudar, ficaria muito grato.

Comment: Resposta editada para melhorar a informação passada.